Searching and replacing words in text file with VBA
This way the code works, but it does not save the change that must be made.  Ideally, it would read the file, make changes and ask to save a copy in a specific folder.
Sub LeituraTxt()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ArqTxt As Object
    Dim Linha As String
 
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    L1 = InputBox("Digite o ComprimentodoPerfil:", "COMPRIMENTO")
    
    arquivo1 = "C:\Users\maicon.caetano\Desktop\Teste VBA\TexteVBA_1.mpf"
    
    Set ArqTxt = FSO.OpenTextFile(arquivo1)
    
    With ArqTxt
    
        Do Until .AtEndOfStream
        
                Linha = .ReadLine
                If Linha = "F2" Then
                Linha = L1
                
                End If
        
        Loop
    
    End With
    
    ArqTxt.Close
    
    Set ArqTxt = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub


mpf  is a rather uncommon file extension. Are you sure it's a plain text file?

It has to be in MPF, as this file will be directed to a machine that runs MPF files

I don't mind about the extension itself, just about the content of the file (and I never heard about that extension). So with other words: Can you open the file with Notepad or something simular?

Yes, the file can be opened in Notepad

Try using RegEx.

#ENIAC RegEx is not the problem here - a simple replace will do. However, what OP need is code to read the file content into a buffer, do the replace and write the modified content back to either the original file or to a copy.

This question is similar to: Read/Parse text file line by line in VBA. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
